# How to save texting characters e.g lol, ASAP from text box to .txt in full abbreviation using WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new in programming. I have a Text Box for typing a message and a button to save message in .txt file. When a user type in text box Hi lol you are funny and press save button. The text file receive like Hi lol laughing at loud you are funny.

Can somebody help me how I can do this? I have done the dictionary class just don't know how to call this class on main window and implement either on button event or text box event to make a message as I mentioned above. Thank you.

```
class SMSTextSpeak
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public SMSTextSpeak()
    {

        dictionary.Add("LOL", "Laughing out loud");
        dictionary.Add("404", "I haven't a clue");
        dictionary.Add("B4N", "Bye for now");
        dictionary.Add("ADN", "Any day now");
        dictionary.Add("GOL", "Giggling out loud");
        dictionary.Add("IMO", "In my opinion");
        dictionary.Add("LY", "Love ya");
        dictionary.Add("PM", "Private message");
        dictionary.Add("TGIF", "Thank God it's friday");
        dictionary.Add("YW", "You're welcome");
    }

    public string Expand(string abbreviation)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsValue(abbreviation))
        {
            string expansion = dictionary[abbreviation];
            return expansion;
        }
        return abbreviation;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll have to break your input (string) into words (using `string.Split(' ')` for example. Then if a word is in the dictionary, replace it?. You can simply use `string.Replace(s1,s2)` where s1 is a word from the dic and s2 what you want, and you'll probably want to match the upper case to avoid replacing parts of words. you can also use a regex and add spaces before/after i guess

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. May I ask where I have to implement this code on button click event or textbox event? Should I keep the dictionary class as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `Expand` method:

```
public string Expand(string message)
{
    string[] splits = message.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < splits.Length; i++)
    {
        string key = dictionary.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x == splits[i].ToUpper());
        if (key != null)
        {
            splits[i] = (key + " " + dictionary[key]).ToLower();
        }
    }

    return string.Join(" ", splits);
}
```

Invoke it:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SMSTextSpeak speak = new SMSTextSpeak();

    // for testing
    string inputText = "Hi lol you are funny";
    string outputText = speak.Expand(inputText);  // get: Hi lol laughing out loud you are funny
 }
```

Comment: What about line breaks?

Comment: Show me the problem please.

Comment: Then, what's the problem?

Comment: Have you use the `outputText`?

Comment: While the `inputText = "Hi lol you are funny"`, the `outputText ` must be `Hi lol laughing out loud you are funny`.

Comment: Form your above code, may you want `string line = speak.Expand(textBoxMessageID.Text); string line1 = speak.Expand(textBoxSenderNumber.Text); string line2 = speak.Expand(textBoxSMS.Text); ......`.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding my comment, I think you're looking for this:

```
public string Expand(string abbreviation)
{
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(abbreviation))
    {
        return dictionary[abbreviation];
    }
    return abbreviation;
}
```

look at the keys, return the value, not the other way around.

Comment: hmmm ... your expand works on 1 word. You'll have to loop on all the words in your text, and "expand" them. I would build a `StringBuilder` and for each word in the original word (use `Split` and `Foreach`) add the "expanded" word to the string builder. Then I'd set that as the result